# Why does only "Strength" appear when I try to compute stability of centrality indices in my network analysis?

Tags: r, graph, graph-theory, network-analysis

[image]

I have just estimated the network accuracy of my network analysis using the nonparametric bootstrap procedure. The next step is computing the stability of the centrality indices, using something like this formula: bootnet(Network, n=Boots=1000, type = "case"). When I go to plot this, only the measure of "Strength" appears, when Betweenness and Closeness should also appear (see the attached graph). I tried using the "include = c("Betweeness", "Closeness", "Strength"), in the formula but still only Strength appears. How can I make all three indices appear on the plot?

I was expecting all three indices to appear on the plot like they usually would (betweenness, closeness, strength).